# CakePHP Acl controlled application failed ARO/ACO lookup - Permissions not registering

Tags: mysql, cakephp, acl, cakephp-2.3

I am building an profile based application. I am attempting to use the simple acl controlled application tutorial found here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html, to create my groups and permissions. I have run into some problems getting the permissions to function when logged in as different users. I have an admin, manager, and user group. I have set ACOs and AROs as well as added permissions to each group. Here is my

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'Acl',
        'Auth'=>array(
            'loginRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'index'),
            'logoutRedirect'=>array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'index'),
            'authError'=>'You cannot access that page',
            'authorize'=>array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
        ),
        'Session'
    );

    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        return true;
    }

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->authorize = array(
            'Actions' => array(
                'userModel' => 'User',
                'actionPath' => 'users'
            )
        );

        $this->Auth->allow('display');

        $this->set('logged_in', $this->Auth->loggedIn());
        $this->set('current_user', $this->Auth->user());

    }

}
```

UserController.php

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('view');
    }



    public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('Post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your username/password combination was incorrect');
            }
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
```

The error that I am getting right now is:

```
Warning (512): DbAcl::check() - Failed ARO/ACO node lookup in permissions check. Node references:
Aro: Array
Permission::check() - CORE/Cake/Model/Permission.php, line 94
DbAcl::check() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/Acl/DbAcl.php, line 73
AclComponent::check() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/AclComponent.php, line 109
ActionsAuthorize::authorize() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/ActionsAuthorize.php, line 40
AuthComponent::isAuthorized() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php, line 412
AuthComponent::startup() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php, line 336
ObjectCollection::trigger() - CORE/Cake/Utility/ObjectCollection.php, line 132
call_user_func - [internal], line ??
CakeEventManager::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Event/CakeEventManager.php, line 248
Controller::startupProcess() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 671
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 184
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 162
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 109
```

For some reason it can't access the permissions. And I can't seem to find a solution to fix this. Any help is would be great! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Those error usually because you add a function/method in your controller but you did not re-populate your acos and aros_acos table.

you need to populate your acos table

./Console/cake AclExtras.AclExtras aco_sync

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/part-two.html

once populated, then we need to assign permission of this new method to our aros_acos table

$this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Posts/myNewCustomMethod');

then run the initDB function again. The tutorial is very clear step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Is warning msj, just to check: put this lines in your function beforeFilter to check.. if is ok, just focus in your permision's..

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    // For CakePHP 2.0
    $this->Auth->allow('*');
    // For CakePHP 2.1 and up
    $this->Auth->allow();
    // or you can put the view
    $this->Auth->allow('index','edit','add','login','delete');
}
```